# CPT Archive pre_get_posts not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I’m confused why the below is not working, i have half a dozen posts within the custom post type local-attractions however, the below tells the archive page to only show 1 (for pagination navigation purposes)  .

Normal code on the archive-local-attractions.php page as well, i’m confused can anyone help?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_archive' );

   function custom_post_type_archive( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('local-attractions') ) {

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );

   }

}
```

Normal code on the page as well...

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>




                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                                <?php the_title(); ?>


                <?php endwhile; ?>



            <?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
&& is_post_type_archive('local-attractions')
```

is_post_type_archive isn't set yet, WP is still deciding this, hence the call to `pre
_get_posts`. Instead use:

```
&& $query->is_post_type_archive('local-attractions')
```

The same is true of any other `is_` type methods, use the `$query` object, else you might be asking these questions about a completely different query and getting confusing results

Comment: Thank you, it was my own fault for some reason the pre_get posts query wont work with `'nopaging' => true` needs to be `'nopaging' => false` but surely you're telling it to have a archive page? Will pagination work with `'nopaging' => false` though?